# Are there nice wedding-related quotes in Doctor Who?

Tags: doctor-who, quotes

Two of my friends are getting married. They're both huge Doctor Who geeks, and actually met through a DW RPG. Their wedding invitation contained a very subtle DW reference (you wouldn't have been able to tell unless you were very familiar with the show yourself.)

Doctor Who's been running long enough that there are quite a few nice quotes for basically every occasion in life. I was hoping someone would know a nice wedding-related one, or maybe one about love, that I could include in a wedding card?

Comment: What was the reference?

Comment: I'm having trouble thinking of classic Who episodes that involved weddings. I can think of companions (like Jo) that got married, but I don't recall the weddings making it into the episode. Romana nearly got married in one of the Key of Time episodes, but I doubt the quotes would be happy ones there.

Comment: There was an episode of _Sarah Jane Adventures_ titled _The Wedding of Sarah Jane Smith_, though I don't remember any good wedding-related quotes from there.

Comment: @Loïc Wolff: The wedding invitation had the design on the back of the Master's fob watch embossed into it. If you're not familiar with the design, it just looks like a pretty, abstract graphic.

Comment: How is this not a list question? [See this Meta discussion.](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/730/why-was-this-question-not-closed/731#731)

Comment: @neilfein - Because who wants to be the Scrooge who votes against true love and Dr Who being in the same room?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From *[The Big Bang](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1607759/quotes)*:

> **The Doctor:**  When you wake up, you'll have a mum and dad, and you
>  won't even remember me. Well, you'll remember me a little. I'll be a
>  story in your head. But that's OK: we're all stories, in the end. Just
>  make it a good one, eh? Because it was, you know, it was the best: a
>  daft old man, who stole a magic box and ran away. Did I ever tell you
>  I stole it? Well, I borrowed it; I was always going to take it back.
>  Oh, that box, Amy, you'll dream about that box. It'll never leave you.
>  Big and little at the same time, brand-new and ancient, and the bluest
>  blue, ever.

(padding)

> Amy remembers at her wedding that this perfectly describes the TARDIS:
>
>  **Amy Pond:** Something old, something new, something borrowed...
>  something blue.

**upd 21 Aug**: from *[Love and Monsters](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0766171/quotes)*:

> When you're a kid, they tell you it's all... grow up. Get a job. Get
>   married. Get a house. Have a kid, and that's it. But the truth is, the
>   world is so much stranger than that. It's so much darker. And so much
>   madder. And so much better.

Comment: This was the first thing that sprang to mind after reading the question.

Answer (score 20):

In the 10th Doctor episode, [The Runaway Bride](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0827573/), the Doctor says:

> Ahh! The wedding! That's right, you're getting married! That's it! Best day of your life, walking down the aisle... Oh, your body's a battleground, there's a chemical war inside! Adrenaline, acetylcholine, **wham** go the endorphins! You're *cooking*! Yeah! You're like a walking oven, a press cooker, a microwave, all churning away; the buttons reach boiling point and **shazzam**...

I think that part of this would suit a wedding card, perhaps even as a reference rather than a direct quotation (in the same way that their reference was subtle).  In your message, mention adrenaline, acetylcholine, and endorphins; perhaps suggest that they'll enjoy their new oven, press cooker, and microwave (but they should be careful when reaching boiling point).  It seems like you could work that into an otherwise normal message, but the astute Doctor Who fan would catch that this was a reference.

There's another reference to marriage in the 11th Doctor episode, [The Big Bang](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1607759/):

> DOCTOR: Are you married, River?
>
> RIVER: Are you asking?
>
> DOCTOR: Yes.
>
> RIVER: Yes.
>
> DOCTOR: No. Hang on. Did you think I was asking you to marry me or asking if you were married?
>
> RIVER: Yes.
>
> DOCTOR: No, but was that yes or yes?
>
> RIVER: Yes.

It's harder to see how you could work this into the card, unless it was just a plain quotation. If their proposal was anything like this, then perhaps it would be suitable.

Although weddings and marriage occasionally came up with Doctors 1 through 7 (e.g. several companions married when they left the Doctor), I cannot recall or find any good quotes about marriage or weddings from these episodes.

Comment: The 10th Doctor's "I'm burning up a sun just to say goodbye" in Doomsday is a great quote about love, too, but probably not something appropriate for a wedding :)

Comment: The Doctor tells Ace he hates unrequited love in Ghost Light. The full quote includes a lot of other things, though.

Answer (score 16):

The Daleks' old favourite, YOU WILL COMPLY, could be used in place of "love, honour and obey".

Answer (score 15):

I know it's late but these quotes are too fantastic to pass up on and frankly, this shows up on an engine search & Doctor/Geek weddings are becoming more of a trend.

> But I'll tell you what it will be: the trip of a lifetime!
>
> ~ Ninth Doctor
>
> The good things don’t always soften the bad, but vice-versa, the bad things don’t necessarily spoil the good things and make them unimportant.”
>
> ~ The Eleventh Doctor

(a nicer and geekier way of saying 'for better or for worse')

> You know when sometimes, you meet someone so beautiful – and then you actually talk to them, and five minutes later they’re as dull as a brick; but then there’s other people. And you meet them and you think, ‘Not bad, they’re okay,’ and then when you get to know them… Their face just sort of becomes them, like their personality’s written all over it, and they just – they turn into something so beautiful. Rory’s the most beautiful man I’ve ever met.”
>
> ~ Amy Pond

(just exchange Rory's name for the Grooms name)

> There’s a lot of things you need to get across this universe. Warp drive… wormhole refractors… You know the thing you need most of all? You need a hand to hold.
>
> ~ Tenth Doctor

Answer (score 8):

> If there's one thing I believe in -- just one! -- I believe in her.
>
> ~ The Ninth Doctor
>
> Allons-y!
>
> ~ The Tenth Doctor

Also, when I wrote a love letter to my fiancé after the proposal, I referenced that he is the Doctor (he's a med student) and that I would forever be his companion.  It's just a reference, not a quote . . . but it made him tear up!

Answer (score 4):

Not strictly Doctor Who, but in Torchwood, Miracle Day:

> *(At a wedding)*
>
> ANGELO: Look at them. What are their chances?
>
> JACK: That’s what makes it so brave and wonderful. Making a promise and going forward. Doesn’t matter what happens in the future. Right now it’s real, and it happens, and it’s true.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so this is also my issue I'm having in finding quotes for my wedding speech (bride is wearing a tardis garter for her groom XD) but I also have one to add that I found earlier :

> Hold hands. That's what you're meant to do. Keep doing that and don't let go. That's the secret.
>
> -11th Doctor, from *Hide*

Answer (score 1):

when the doctor and river actually get married. its called the wedding of river song.
river tells the doctor she can't kill him until he knows that

"
You are loved by so many and so much and  by no one more than me"